# Cassandra data type to ignite data type

Tags: java, cassandra, ignite

I'm using Apache Ignite 2.1 with Apache Cassandra 3 , while converting Cassandra data type **Time** to java.sql.time in ignite don't supports and i have read that [Cassandra](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.2/manual/#cql-to-java-type-mapping) return type for time is long.

I simply want to convert this long to time format before storing it in ignite.Is there any way to achieve that ?

Answer (score 0):

Cassandra Time type, as explained [here](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cql/types.html#times), stores the value up to the nanoseconds, while `java.sql.time` stores the value [up to the milliseconds](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Time.html). You just need to standardize the time to be in the same unit and then create the object.

Assuming that you are storing the Cassandra Time value into the variable `cassandraTime`, you should be able to create the `java.sql.Time` object with:

```
java.sql.Time convertedTime = new java.sql.Time(cassandraTime / 1000000);
```